# PHP, openId - Can not write into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, openid, steam

Hello I am trying to set up a game betting site. I use openId to transfer data from steam to my website. But this "bug" occured while ago. I can not write new row for each new user that connects. It was working 2 days ago. I dont think i changed anything but it is not working so something had to change. My code is quite long so I will only post the part I think is problematic.
So here it is. It is supposed to write new row for new user as i said.

```
        if($openid->validate()) 
    {
            $id = $openid->identity;
            // identity is something like: http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561197960435530
            // we only care about the unique account ID at the end of the URL.
            $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
            preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);
            echo "Sucesfully logged in (steamID: $matches[1])\n";

            $url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$_STEAMAPI&steamids=$matches[1]";
            $json_object= file_get_contents($url);
            $json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

            foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player)
            {
                $sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM users_steam WHERE steamid = $player->steamid";
                $query_id = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_fetch_id);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_id)==0){
                    $sql_steam = "INSERT INTO users_steam (name, steamid, avatar, loggedin, tradeurl) VALUES ('$player->personaname', '$player->steamid', '$player->avatar',' ',' ')";
                    mysqli_query($conn,$sql_steam);}

                $_SESSION["id"] = $player->steamid;
                $_SESSION["name"] = $player->personaname;
                $_SESSION["url"] = $player->profileurl;
                $_SESSION["smallavatar"] = $player->avatar;
                $_SESSION["mediumavatar"] = $player->avatarmedium;
                $_SESSION["largeavatar"] = $player->avatarfull;
            }
    }
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that it does not show any errors or anything. It just doesnt react and behaves like it passed. For example the session indexes are set after player log in. It just does not write into mysql.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Can you [edit] in some more context, and possible error logs from the php server?

Comment: It does not throw any errors. Wait let me check php error log

Comment: I checked error log and no error there. I dont really get what is happening.

Comment: The issue is that this code after foreach(){} is supposed to write new row into a database right? I am sorry I am quite new to php and mysql databases

Comment: Have you verified that `$conn` is a valid connection?

Comment: yes i think i did. it would throw an error otherwise
https://snag.gy/RJKOIX.jpg

Comment: i tested everything and it only seems that the line in foreach -> if starting with $sql_steam is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem was that I added new required column into my table. Thanks for effort Matt Clark!